# Xamarin.Forms, XAML - How to display image with color overlay

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, background, xamarin.forms

I'm building a layout in my Xamarin.Forms app, and I need to display an image with a transparent color overlay. I have a `Grid` layout that displays the image and stacks a `ContentView` on top of it with a semitransparent background color. As you can see in the images below, the `ContentView` (and I suspect the containing `Grid`) simply refuses to shrink to the size of the image (the largest item in the `Grid`).

How can I do this?

I've tried all kinds of different `VerticalOptions` on the different views and nothing I've done so far has worked, but I'm new to Forms so confirm if you think the solution might be basic. :)

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Image Source="PlayerBackground.png" />
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="#88000000"></ContentView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image/>
        <Label/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image: Mockup]

And here's what I'm actually getting:

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

Comment: would love to connect to talk about the use of technology for the Kingdom. https://www.rockrms.com/connect-with-jon

Answer (score 7):

`Aspect` property is the key.

```
   <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="PlayerBackground.png" />
        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="#000000" Opacity="0.8"/>
    </Grid>
```

Or you could use `CachedImage` which is `Image` replacement:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
        <!-- First two digits from HexColor = ALPHA channel -->
        <fftransformations:TintTransformation HexColor="#60ff0000" EnableSolidColor="true"/>
    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Disclaimer: I'm an author.

Comment: I know how to make the color transparent, my question is about how to make the view creating the color overlay fit the image, not extend beyond it.

Comment: You need to also use image `Aspect` property, I'll modify my answer, the second solution will also work fine.

Comment: @DanielLuberda I use that transformation in ViewCell, on binding context change override I reach that transform and change HexColor proeprty value, I use RecycleElement on Listview and on andorid while scrolling it sets different colors every time on same objects

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the HorizontalOptions and Vertical Options on the ContentView.

Also you can use a Grid instead of a ContentView with HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions set to FillAndExpand

Comment: This is actually an answer, even though it looks like it should be a followup comment. It's best to write *Try blah blah* rather than *Have you tried blah blah*.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [IconView](https://github.com/andreinitescu/IconApp) which is very handy. As per your solution, you can try as follows.

First include [IconView.cs](https://github.com/andreinitescu/IconApp/blob/master/IconApp/IconApp/IconView.cs) in your Xamarin.Forms project.

Then try the following.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
    <local:IconView Source="PlayerBackground.png"
        VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        Foreground="Green"/>

    <local:IconView Source="Bird.png"
        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Foreground="Blue"/>
</Grid>
```

Change the `Foreground` value to whatever colour you want. Hope this answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use FF CachedImage, you can apply color overlay like so:

```
img_radar.Transformations.Add(new TintTransformation() { HexColor = "ffffff" });

forms:CachedImage Source="img_radar_off" x:Name="img_radar" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <forms:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                             <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tapped_radar"/>
                        </forms:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    </forms:CachedImage>
```